# Splitview in FlexiPage in Salesforce lightning

Tags: dynamic, flexipages

When creating a lightning page we have a template which can be selected.

But these templates have a static grid.

Something like these: [image]

But is there a way where I can select a template (Header and Right Sidebar) and then split the main region into two section and drag and drop standard components side by side.

[image]

Just like we do for fields Section.

Has someone implemented something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent LWC component and use slds-size* classes to split the screen space as per need. I don't think there's standard way to do this.

Comment: But how do you place OOTB standard components in LWC? I believe I should have mentioned standard components in my initial question. Apologies.